# Flutter Error: I can't use english_words package

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently started learning flutter. I was working on the 'package:english_words/english_words.dart' package. I have successfully imported it by modifying the pubspec.yaml file by adding 'english_words: ^4.0.0 inside dependencies and on the main.dart file child:Text(wordPair.asPascalCase) is throwing an error.
The output I got after running it is :
lib/main.dart:17:23: Error: Not a constant expression.

child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase),

```
        ^^^^^^^^
```

Restarted application in 299ms.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0eGW.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5RSD.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyg9p.jpg)

Comment: You have to remove `const` keyword before the `Center` widget on line 16, since you cannot know the `wordPair.asPascalCase` at compile time, i.e. it is not `const`.

More info [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const)

Answer (score 1):

`Error: Not a constant expression`

This means you are using a value as a constant but it will change in run time

Just remove the `const` modifier , like below

```
Center( child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase))
```